# For homomorphism $\phi: G\to H$, if $G_{1}\leq G$ and $|G_{1}|=n$, then $|\phi(G_{1})|$ divides $n$.

Tags: group-theory, proof-explanation, group-homomorphism

Could someone please help me with this proof? I am not sure how to show this...

> For homomorphism $\phi: G\to H$, if $G_{1}\leq G$ and $|G_{1}|=n$, then $|\phi(G_{1})|$ divides $n$.

My work so far: By definition of $H$, $\phi(G_{1}) \subset H$. Since $\phi$ is a homomorphism that sends a group to a group, $\phi(G_{1})$ is a group. Then $\phi(G_{1})\leq H$.

> I want to use properties of $\phi$ but I am not sure what I can say...

Comment: *Hint.* Use $\operatorname{Im} \phi \cong G/\ker\phi$ (so $|\operatorname{Im}\phi| = |G|/|\ker\phi|$. Why?) and Lagrange's theorem.

Comment: $\forall g\in G_1$, $g^n=e$. Thus $\phi(g)^n=e$ thus $|\phi(G_1)|$ divides $n$.

Comment: @HanulJeon Thank you, this makes a lot of sense for me!

Comment: @Qurultay I see now. I will try this out and see if I can understand. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may think in the following way:

By ***Lagrange Theorem***, $|\phi(G_1)|= |G_1/(G_1\cap\ker \phi)| $ divids $G_1$.

I hope this suffices to give you the idea.

$:\,)$

Comment: Thank you, this helps a lot in my understanding!

Comment: You're welcome. $\ddot\smile$